# Notification parallelism in Observable

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I have the following observable

```
IObservable<Work> observable = SomeMethodToGetWorkToDo();
```

Every time `OnNext` is called on the above, I need the work done in a separate thread. Each work is going to take long to finish so I can't have other `Work` items in the queue waiting so long there are enough system resources.

I thought `ObserveOn` would solve my problem, but when I run a few `Console.WriteLine` calls to see the thread IDs, I saw the same thread ID for each notification call.

How can I make sure of parallelism in `OnNext`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to transform the "work to do" into a series of "work is being done" tokens that you then collect.  Easiest way is to use TPL to execute the work as a Task (which will end up running the Tasks on the Thread Pool).  Something like this:

```
observable
    .SelectMany(work => Task.Run(() => DoWork(work))
    .Subscribe(workResult => Console.WriteLine("a work item was completed"));
```

Comment: Why `SelectMany` instead of `Select`?

Comment: `SelectMany` will convert each work item into a `Task<TResult>` and then unwrap each task into a `TResult` so you end up with an `IObservable<TResult>` stream.  With `Select` you'd have a stream of `IObservable<Task<TResult>>`.

Comment: I would have suggested using `Observable.Start` rather than `Task.Run` as it's better to stay within Rx that to switch back and forth from TPL.

Comment: I have run some numbers in console, I found that there were 4 unique threads used at most and some tasks were waiting. Is there anyway to not have tasks waiting?

Answer (score 3):

`ObserveOn` works best as follows:

```
var sample = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

sample
    .SelectMany(l => Observable.Return(l)
        .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default /*or NewThreadScheduler.Default */)
    )
    .Select(l => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    .Take(9)
    .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

The trick is to get the different items to be processed on different threads, they have to be on different streams.

Comment: I am looking at this again after 10 months, and realize how clever your trick is.